# Java float to IEEE-754 hexadecimal?

Tags: java, hex

I've been searching for an answer to this all over for about 2 hours now, I can't seem to get my head around it. I need to convert a 32 bit single floating point value in java to a hexadecimal string.

I've narrowed it down to IEEE 754. So I need to somehow convert a float in Java such as:

```
    float num = 504.0f;
```

to this value: 43FC0000

Any help would be appreciated as I really need this for a RTE project I'm working on.
Thanks

Comment: @DavidWallace You should submit that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That'll be `Integer.toHexString(Float.floatToIntBits(num)).toUpperCase()`

Not sure if you want to left pad this with zeroes.

Comment: You just saved my 2-3 day efforts to convert lua function in java.