# Is there a way to display a floating number in its' binary form?

Tags: java, format

Let's say I have a floating number in java. How can I print it in it's binary form? Is there a simple method to use in the java library? I am talking about IEEE 754 floating point. Or would I have to write it from scratch?

I'd also like to print it out.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/397700/645270) will work (scroll down for more tips)

Comment: I answered something very similar to this yesterday - see [Java float to IEEE-754 hexadecimal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230748/java-float-to-ieee-754-hexadecimal)

Comment: You can do `Integer.toBinaryString(Float.floatToIntBits(f))`

Comment: What is your date type? Integer,Float,Double?

Comment: Looking at Double to iee754 bias 127 binary.

Comment: Whoops, I meant float.

Comment: @munchschair I have tried so many ways to convert double into binary but no success and now you need it only for float. :)

Comment: Why not open up a question for that then bro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Integer.toBinaryString(Float.floatToIntBits(FloatNumber));
```

**Example:**

```
class FloatToBinary { 
      public static void main( String ... args ) { 

      int BitRep =   Float.floatToIntBits(12345.12346f); //Bit Representation of the Float
      System.out.println(BitRep); //1178657918

      String BinString = Integer.toBinaryString(BitRep); //Binary representation in String
      System.out.println(BinString); //1000110010000001110010001111110



             }
        }
```

**EDIT**

Looks like an identical question has already been answered: 
[how to convert a string of binary values to a float and vice-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157664/java-how-to-convert-a-string-of-binary-values-to-a-float-and-vice-versa)

Comment: What if you want it signed?